# How to send params to a method?

Tags: ruby, google-api-client, google-api-ruby-client

I am trying to make a query to Webmaster Tool api using the Ruby Client.

```
params = {
  start_date: "2015-01-14",
  end_date: "2015-01-14"
}

AuthWebmastersService.query_search_analytics("http://www.ex.com/", params)
```

When I'm trying to make that request I get `ArgumentError (unknown keywords: start_date, end_date)`, why is this happening?

[Here](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/generated/google/apis/webmasters_v3/service.rb#L86) is the method definition.

Comment: This looks strange, I've posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34794043/477037) that focuses on the underlying problem.

Comment: `query_search_analytics("http://www.ex.com/", params, {})` should work if `params` actually is the `search_analytics_query_request_object`

Comment: @Stefan, yes what you said is working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work as expected, because Ruby converts your hash to *keyword arguments*, i.e.

```
query_search_analytics("...", {start_date: "2015-01-14", end_date: "2015-01-14"})
```

becomes:

```
query_search_analytics("...", start_date: "2015-01-14", end_date: "2015-01-14")
```

To get the expected result, you have to append an empty hash:

```
query_search_analytics("http://www.ex.com/", params, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a ruby issue with auto-expanding the last argument if is a hash.

Two workarounds:

## 1 - Use a proper object instead of a hash:

```
params = Google::Apis::WebmastersV3::SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest.new(
  start_date: "2015-01-14",
  end_date: "2015-01-14"
)

AuthWebmastersService.query_search_analytics("http://www.ex.com/", params)
```

## 2 - Append an empty hash as a param:

```
params = {
  start_date: "2015-01-14",
  end_date: "2015-01-14"
}

AuthWebmastersService.query_search_analytics("http://www.ex.com/", params, {})
```

Comment: And FYI, I updated the readme for the API client to warn about this nuance.

Answer (score 0):

This error:
`ArgumentError (unknown keywords: start_date, end_date)`
is telling you that you specified the wrong keyword attributes.

Your method takes:

```
def query_search_analytics(site_url, search_analytics_query_request_object = nil, fields: nil, quota_user: nil, user_ip: nil, options: nil, &block)
```

- site_url as first argument
- search_analytics_query_request_object - as second argument with default value nil
- multiple keyword arguments (and a block)

When you call your method like you wrote:

- site_url will have value "http://www.ex.com/"
- search_analytics_query_request_object will be nill
- and hash will be applied to keyword arguments and ruby will raise the error as there are no startDate and endDate keyword argument

What you need to do is to:

```
query_search_analytics("http://www.ex.com/", options: params)
```

Comment: Fixes, the `unknown keywords` problem, but the params are not picked :(

Answer (score -2):

Because it only takes the keyword arguments `fields`, `quota_user`, `user_ip`, `options`, and `start_date`, `end_date` are not among them.

Comment: `query_search_analytics(site_url, search_analytics_query_request_object = nil, fields: nil, quota_user: nil, user_ip: nil, options: nil, &block)`